# Entity Framework Core zero-or-one to zero-or-one relation. Which way is more recent?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I just want to ask something about Entity Framework Core zero-or-one to zero-or-one relation. When I search to documents about zero or one or zero or one relation, I'm finding different sources which is showing me a two way. First way is about to using

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Configure Student & StudentAddress entity
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasOptional(s => s.Address)
                .WithRequired(ad => ad.Student);
}
```

and the other way is about to using

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
                .HasOne(a => a.B)
                .WithOne(b => b.A)
                .HasForeignKey<A>(a => a.BId);
```

which they are calling fluent api.

Im just not sure about which one i have to use because when use the first way,visual studio is not defining those hasOptional and WithRequired things.
Can anyone tell me which way is more recent .

i allready checked out those library or package things.

Comment: Is `HasOptional` available for EF Core?

Comment: That is the thing im trying to solve. Old sources are using HasOptional and with required. When i search from the microsoft website there is not something like that.

Comment: Have you tried to use it EF Core? =) As far as I can see this API was for EF 6 and is not present in EF Core.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply guru. I lost myself in those old and new informations and i got confused about it. u really helped me even if u are thinking its a easy thing. Thanks again !